# SimpleXML PHP - Why DOM functions don't work, cdata trouble

Tags: php, simplexml, cdata

Ive been trying every way possible to create cdata entries in my xml.  My latest attempt is as follows.  I can't even get passed for the first statement where im creating a new DOMDocument.  Any ideas?

```
<?php
$xml = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<cars>
    <make name="Ford">
        <model>Mustang</model>
    </make>
    <make name="Honda">
        <model>Accord</model>
    </make>
</cars>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadXML($xml);


$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
print "working";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have any characters before the XML declaration.  Remove the line break at `$xml = '`.

The neatest solution would be to use heredoc syntax:

```php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<cars>
    <make name="Ford">
        <model>Mustang</model>
    </make>
    <make name="Honda">
        <model>Accord</model>
    </make>
</cars>
XML;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: [DOMDocument::createCDATASection](http://php.net/manual/domdocument.createcdatasection.php)

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<cars>
    <make name="Ford">
        <model>Mustang</model>
    </make>
    <make name="Honda">
        <model>Accord</model>
    </make>
</cars>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$cdataNode = $dom->createCDATASection('<&>');
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($cdataNode);

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<cars>
    <make name="Ford">
        <model>Mustang</model>
    </make>
    <make name="Honda">
        <model>Accord</model>
    </make>
<![CDATA[<&>]]></cars>
```